# In Node.js, res.render is returning a 404 error on router.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, ejs

I'm building my first Node application and having some trouble displaying the page that I want with a GET request. I have installed ejs (opinions welcome on that!) so my understanding is that I do not need to define the 'views' folder. Here is my routes file so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Event = require('../models/event')

router.get('/'), function(req, res, next){
   /* Event.find({}).then(function(events){
       res.send(events);
   });
    });*/
    res.render('../../index');
 };

router.post('/events', (req, res) => {
    Event.create(req.body);
    res.send({type: POST})
});


module.exports = router;
```

The database is connecting just fine, which I can see with the code that I have commented out in the get request. But for some reason I can't render my index file. My file structure is as follows:

File tree:
[image: File tree]

So I need to go up two levels, correct? I tried index, index.ejs, ../index, views/index, nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: this is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
var path = require("path");

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(routes);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

mongoose.connect('mongodb://junk:junk@ds141242.mlab.com:41242/alaska-events');


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  });
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you need to set `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` so that your views folder location is known and you don't need to know how many levels up/down to go to find it.

Comment: add: app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); in you server.js

Comment: Paolo, sorry I should have specified I already have the view engine set for ejs. Andy, I added what you said and also defined `var path = require("path");` because I was getting an error ("ReferenceError: path is not defined"). Still no luck.

Comment: don't ever put credentials here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone, turned out to be just a typo. `router.get('/'), function(req, res, next)` should have been `router.get('/', function(req, res, next)`.

Answer (score 1):

views folder is placed directly in root folder, and using we app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); point it to views folder. So in render directly mention the view name.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean like

`router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   res.render('views/index');
});`

I have tried that also

Comment: Its just res.render('index');   ......... Not view 'views/index' as in set path we have mentioned the path already.